# custom magento admin access permission - add product only

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I would like to set up a magento admin user with role permission of adding new product only as well as only be able to modify those products that are added by this user only. Can anyone tell me which file that i need to modify in order to set up this role permission?

Thanks in advance,
jason

Comment: Hi, have you implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

In backend go to:
System -> Permissions -> Roles -> Add New Role -> Role Resources

Set the role by checking one or more items and give it a Role Name. Save the role.

Go to:
Systen -> Permissions - > Users and create a New User or choose a user from the list.
In the User menu, choose the User Role.

Comment: hi, i know how to create the new role and assign user. but my question is that under "Role Resources", there is no option where i can choose to allow this user to add product only. I only see "Manage Products" option. If i checked this one, then this user can also delete all the products. hope this explanation helps.